# Как добавить jar библиотеку к проекту вручную?

Tags: java, jar

У меня есть jar библиотека и файл Main.java. Мне необходимо создать исполнительные файлы для компилирования и запуска (compile.cmd и run.cmd)

Скажите пожалуйста как мне это сделать, в частности - какие ключи использовать?

Comment: Какая структура проекта и какими средствами разработки/сборки вы пользуетесь?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
javac -cp lib.jar -d . Main.java
```

и

```
java -cp .;lib.jar com.example.Main
```

Comment: Параметр `-d .` необязателен. По умолчанию `javac` генерирует `class` файлы там же, где находятся соответствующие `java` файлы.

Comment: @РостиславКрасный если в Main.java указан пакет, то загрузить Main.class из текущего каталога не получится.